# How to mock optimizelySDK.createInstance().onReady() using Jest?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jestjs, mocking, optimizely

Here is my mock file `__mocks__/@optimizely/optimizely-sdk.js`

```
const optimizelySDK = jest.requireActual('@optimizely/optimizely-sdk')

optimizelySDK.createInstance().onReady = () => ({ success: false }))

module.exports = optimizelySDK
```

Here is my test file `Optimizely.test.js`

```
import optimizelySDK from '@optimizely/optimizely-sdk'

test('onReady', () => {
  const response = optimizelySDK.createInstance().onReady()
  expect(response).toBe({ success: false })
})
```

I think I might be going about this all wrong. This worked perfectly when I try this with lodash. I believe this is because optimizelySDK is a class. I think I should be mocking that instead. How do I successfully mock and test optimizelySDK?

Comment: What's the test result? Is there any error?

Comment: It fails, receives promise {}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone who came across this on Google, I had the same problem and got it working with jest:

```
jest.mock('@optimizely/optimizely-sdk', () => ({
  ...jest.requireActual('@optimizely/optimizely-sdk'),
  createInstance: () => ({
    getEnabledFeatures: jest.fn().mockReturnValueOnce(['featureA', 'featureB']),
    onReady: jest.fn().mockResolvedValueOnce({ status: 200 })
  })
}))

describe('my-test', () => {

  it('should pass', async () => {

    const result = await getFeatures()

    console.log(result) // ['featureA', 'featureB']

    // assert on result here
  });
});
```

where my code looked something like:

```
const getFeatures = async (event) => {

  try {
    const optimizelyInstance = optimizelySDK.createInstance({
      sdkKey: process.env.OPTIMIZLEY_SDK_KEY,
    });

    const optimizelyParameters = {}

    return optimizelyInstance.onReady().then(() => {
      const result = optimizelyInstance.getEnabledFeatures('id', optimizelyParameters);

      return result;
    });
  } catch (err) {
    console.error('Could not get features', err);
  }
};
```